# Earth Mover's Distance (EMD) between two distributions of different dimensionality

Tags: normal-distribution, distance, wasserstein

When $x_1\sim N(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$ and $x_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \Sigma_2)$, and $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are both $D$-dimensional, the EMD is well defined and there exists a closed-form solution for it. Is there a meaningful notion of an EMD between two normal distributions of *different* dimensionality?

Comment: Chances are there isn't. You can't change dimensions just moving earth. I can imagine that one could define something projecting both distributions on some "optimal" joint lower-dimensional space, but I don't expect that it exists, and I'm not sure how meaningful that'd be.

Comment: The geometric version of this question is "can I equate length and area?"